# Indexing and cluster in Greenplum database

Tags: indexing, greenplum, clustered-index

I am new to Greenplum database. I have a question.
Is Cluster on table mandatory after creating an index on a column in Greenplum in case of row-based distribution?

Comment: This isn't SQL Server so you don't need indexes.

Answer (score 2):

The "massively parallel" (MPP) nature of Greenplum's software-level architecture, when coupled with the throughput capabilities of modern servers makes indexes unnecessary in most cases.

To say it differently, **the speed of table scans in Greenplum is a feature, rather than a bottleneck**.  Please refer to this great writeup on how MPP works under the hood : https://dwarehouse.wordpress.com/2012/12/28/introduction-to-massively-parallel-processing-mpp-database/

Answer (score 0):

If your data is not updated frequently and you need quickly return the result, you can use clustered index table. it will cost much time. you can build index for the column-oriented table.